# What would be the simplest way to implement Flexigrid with ASP.NET 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, .net-3.5, flexigrid

I've been trying to follow the top Google results for **ASP.NET + Flexigrid for jQuery** such as [CodeProject's](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FlexiGrid.aspx) approach  but they all seem kind of sophisticated, I'm rather looking for something way more basic in terms of simplicity, a kind of *Hello World* approach if you will. I'd be more than happy if you guys would like to share any resource that you might think would be helpful. Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example seems fairly simple to me. [How To Populating a FlexGrid Control with ADO and ASP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189406)

But if you are using ASP.NET 3.5, why would you use a flexgrid instead of a GridView?

Comment: Thanks for your reply pthalacker! To answer your question, basically because our project requires a client-side, dynamic, ajax-enabled grid such as jqGrid or Flexigrid.

Answer (score 1):

simplest way would be to use someone else's code. have you seen http://www.flexigrid-asp.net